# How to use observables in angular2 service calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service call from my component which gets the list of heroes.from that function where it calls another function which has the http request...How can i subscribe to the function call so that i will get the response properly...Here is my plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/UM9STMwaOsgolhBjADjx?p=preview ...
This is how i am calling the service from my component

```
 ngOnInit() { 
              this.heroService.getHeroes()
                 .subscribe(
                  heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                  error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
 }
```

And in my Service class i have called this method which calls another method which has http request and subscribed to that...

```
  getHeroes (){
return this.GetListOfHeroes()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            return data;
        }
        );
}
```

And finally this is the method which gets the list...

```
  GetListOfHeroes(){
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

If i directly call GetListOfHeroes() method from my component it works fine but if i try to call that from another method it shows  this error `this.heroService.getHeroes(...).subscribe is not a function`
Somebody please tell me where i am doing wrong...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map(...)` instead of `.subscribe(...)` in `getHeroes()` like:

```
  getHeroes (){
    return this.GetListOfHeroes()
    .map((data: any) => {
        return data;
    });
  }
```

This way `getHeroes()` returns an `Observable` while with `.subscribe()` it returns a `Subscription` you can't subscribe to.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you should subscribe within the `getHeroes` method since it will return a subscription and not an observable.

```
getHeroes (){
  return this.GetListOfHeroes()
    .subscribe((data: any) => { // <-----
        return data;
    });
}
```

The `subscribe` method can only be called on an observable. The subscription object is usable to cancel the subscription...

In fact, it depends on what you want to do within the `getHeroes` method. You can, for example, leverage the `do` operator or the `map` one. Here is a sample:

```
getHeroes (){
  return this.GetListOfHeroes()
    .do((data: any) => { // <-----
      // do something with data
    })
    .map((data: any) => {
      // return something else in the data flow
      return { attr: 'value' };
    });
}
```